# How do I get an API key from Podio without a return url?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, podio

I want to test the Podio API on my local machine. I don't have a website. When I go to this url to get an api key, it asks me for a return URL. How can I figure out how to use the Podio API without a return URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to use this api key in server-side auth flow then you can use any value as domain, otherwise it should be domain of return URL.

As it is described in more details here: https://developers.podio.com/authentication/server_side
`The redirect_uri must be on the same domain as the domain you specified when you applied for your API Key.`